pendingIntent not getting triggered
i want to add a widget to the home screen , and when i click it , the open with dialog should pop up and open the link associated with the widget ... nothing happens when i click the widget , absolutely nothing
class MyAppWidgetProvider:AppWidgetProvider() {
    companion object { lateinit var text:String }
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d("onReceive", intent.action.toString())
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        if (intent.action == AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE) {
            val appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS)
            if (appWidgetIds != null && appWidgetIds.isNotEmpty()) {
                // This is the ID of the newly created widget
                updateWidget(context, appWidgetIds[0])
            }
        }
        if (intent.action == "GETEDITTEXT") {
            val edittext = intent.getStringExtra("EditText text")
            text = edittext.toString()
        }
        if (intent.action == "OPENBROWSER") {
            val random = Random
            val color = Color.rgb(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256))
            val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)
            remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.widget_text, color)
        }
    }

    private fun updateWidget(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int) {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, text)
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context?,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray?
    ) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
        if (appWidgetIds != null) {
            for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
                val views = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)

                // Intent to open the link
                val intent = Intent(context, MyAppWidgetProvider::class.java).apply {
                    action = "OPENBROWSER"
                    data = Uri.parse(text)
                    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId)
                }

                // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the TextView is clicked
                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

                // Set the PendingIntent to the TextView in the widget
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_text, pendingIntent)

                appWidgetManager?.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
            }
        }
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        val button:Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MyAppWidgetProvider::class.java).apply{
                action = "GETEDITTEXT"
                putExtra("EditText text", findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextText).text.toString())
            }
            sendBroadcast(intent)
            addWidgetToHomeScreen()
        }
    }

    private fun addWidgetToHomeScreen() {
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this)
        val myProvider = ComponentName(this, MyAppWidgetProvider::class.java)
        if (appWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported) {
            appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, null)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't add widget.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

i tried using pending intent , i tried all the life cycle methods , i tried to handle it in onReceive , nothing works
